# How to Add Calendar event in android api level greater than 8?

Tags: android, calendar, cursor, android-contentresolver

How to add Calendar event in android api level greater than 8?

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = null;
try{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8){
        cursor=cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/reminders"), null, null, null, null);
    }else {
        cursor=cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/reminders"), null, null, null, null);
    }
```

but I got cursor null in api level 8 to 10 and but it work on api 4.2.
how to get this cursor for calendar events or remindar?

Answer (score 0):

From your question and code, I'm unclear if you want to actually add a calendar event or query existing calendar events.  If you do want to add a calendar event, you'll want to use an Intent.  For example:

```
Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
calendarIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
calendarIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "the title");
calendarIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "the location");
calendarIntent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "some description");

calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, start);
calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, end);
startActivity(calendarIntent);
```

Where 'start' and 'end' are long values to represent the date.

Comment: I want to add ot get Calendar event on minimum api level 8. for this code required minimum api 14.

Comment: You're right, my apologies.  From what I understand, there's no official API prior to Honeycomb for adding calendar events.  Even if the URI you posted works, it may be inconsistent across all devices.  If you do find a solution, I would be curious to know what it is.  In my own app where I let users add events to their calendar, for the older API levels I just disable this feature.